# reactjs Unexpected token "/"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello i am trying to render a React component dynamically look:

```
render: function() {
    return (
        <form  {...this.props}>
            <div className={'row'}>
                {this.props.fields.map(function(field, index){
                    if (index != 0 &&index%3==0) {
                        return (
                            </div><div className={'row'}>
                            <div className={'col-sm-4'}>
                                ...
                            </div>
                        )
                    } else{
                        return (
                            <div className={'col-sm-4'}>
                                ...
                            </div>
                        )
                    }
                })}
            </div>
        </form>
    );
}
```

but i am getting this error "Parse Error: Line 17: Unexpected token / while parsing file..."

the line 17 in my file is `</div><div className={'row'}>`

There is another way to do this? and is it possible to put all my duplicated code inside a variable?

Obs: i am using browserify(7.0.x) and reactfy(0.17.1)

Comment: It's just a typo `return (</div>`.  You  can't close a tag there because you haven't opened one.

Comment: oh there is any trick to solve this?

Comment: The "trick" is not to do this. Having `</div>` without any opening div element is simply invalid HTML and this is what the parser is complaining about. If you actually want this, you have to put the div (with classname='row') inside your if statement as well.

Answer (score 0):

To formalize the correct answer described by FakeRainBrigand and elaborated on by dirkk in the comments above, here's a modified `render` that fixes the invalid HTML:

```
render: function() {
  return (
    <form  {...this.props}>
      <div className={'row'}>
        {
          this.props.fields.map(function(field, index) {
            if (index !== 0 && index % 3 === 0) {
              return (
                <div className={'row'}>
                  <div className={'col-sm-4'}>
                    {/* Whatever else each field is supposed to do if the index isn't zero but is divisible by three */}
                  </div>
                </div>
              )
            } else {
              return (
                <div className={'col-sm-4'}>
                  {/* Whatever else each field is supposed to do if the index is zero or isn't divisible by three */}
                </div>
              )
            }
          })
        }
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}
```

The issue was in the `if` block, which (with minor code formatting updates) initially looked like this:

```
if (index !== 0 && index % 3 === 0) {
  return (
    </div>
    <div className={'row'}>
      <div className={'col-sm-4'}>
        {/* ... */}
      </div>
  )
}
```

The `</div>` at the start of the block is invalid HTML since it is not associated with an earlier `<div>`--you can't close a tag that hasn't been opened. However, removing the leading `</div>` won't solve the issue: by fixing the indentation it becomes clear that the `</div>` was likely intended to be at the end of this block, as the `div` with class `row` is never closed. The corrected version of this block looks like this:

```
if (index !== 0 && index % 3 === 0) {
  return (
    <div className={'row'}>
      <div className={'col-sm-4'}>
        {/* Whatever else each field is supposed to do if the index isn't zero but is divisible by three */}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```